I exactly want to know what 'now' means
As I know, 'now' has two meanings. one is 'from now on' and the other is 'at this point'.

I don't have time to watch TV now.
Ming is worried now.

Do both 'now' mean 'from now on' because those sentences are simple present?

I am writing a letter now.

Does this 'now' mean 'at this present moment' because this sentence is present continuous?

You mean "I want to know exactly what 'now' means". In all your examples it means 'at the present moment'. In some contexts it can mean 'from now on', for example "You have explained it very clearly, so now I understand".

I would rather say that 'now' can mean 'at this present moment or time (and no other)' or 'at this time and in the future'.

This question seems based on a misapprehension about what "now" means. Typically it means at the present moment, but you can guess whether that will continue to be the case in the future or has been the case in the past. Depending on context, now can also mean in the moment just past or in the moment just to come, and it can be used as a non-temporal linking word similar to "well", or in the present situation, or to mean "sometimes" (as in "now and again", "now one and now another").

@KateBunting So, Is it not about parts of speech? Is it about context? I mean determining what 'now' means.

Meaning almost always depends on context.

Technically I can say, a minute after you say X, "Now you tell me X!" In that case, you told me one minute in the past, but it's now enough to use the word now.

You have given sentences without context. Real communication doesn't happen that way. For all of these, the meaning I would guess would be "at this point." But you could add made-up situations to any of them to change the meaning to "from now on." Like "I used to watch TV as a kid, but now I'm an adult. I don't have time to watch TV now." No verb tense, not even any word choice, can guarantee a meaning so strongly that the context can't change it. We can have no certain meanings without context.

"Now" means "at the present time".  It doesn't mean "from now on"  (for that we would say "from now on")
"I don't have time to watch TV now." means "at this moment in time". Of course we can infer that if someone doesn't have time "now", then they won't have time five seconds in the future. They probably won't have time five minutes in the future (but they might have time time five hours in the future). "Now" is used here to contrast the present time with some other time, that may or may not be explicit: "I don't have time to watch TV now, but if you can wait for half an hour, I'll have finished my housework and then I watch TV with you."
Similarly if "Ming is worried now", she will probably continue being worried for a while.  This is part of the meaning of "worried", not the meaning of "now".
Likewise "I'm writing a letter" (in the continuous) means that the action will take a little time.  Adding "now" doesn't change that.  It means "at this moment in time", and the meaning of "be writing" means that we can infer that you started writing some short time ago, and will continue for some short time into the future.
But "now" means "at the present time".
 There are some other meanings of "now", such as as discourse marker to highlight a sense of urgency etc.

So, Is it not about parts of speech? Is it about context? I mean determining what 'now' means.

Now is an adverb (like many short words, it can also appear as other parts of speech.  But the part of speech is not important here.  The meaning is "at the present time"  and it is usually used for contrast with "other times".

It doesn't always mean at the present time it can mean now and in the future.  We can say from now on to mean now and in the future.  That meaning can also be implied through context, Now I know not to pet rabid bats,  implies something occurred that has taught you this recently, and that you will retain that information going forward.

While this is the most reasonable answer, and while "at this present moment" could be said to be the default meaning, don't you acknowledge that it can sometimes be a shorthand for "now and from now on"? Like Ellie's example, or mine in my comment on the question?

"From now on" means now and the future.  But even in that idiom, "now" means "the present time.  "Now I know not to pet rabid bats" is another example.  "Now" means "at the present time, but the meaning of know is such that you can infer that you will continue to "know" this into the future. I've alluded to various other meanings of "now" as discourse markers etc, but that's not really what we're talking about here.

Compare a sentence like "The price of dingbats will now be $5", to the sentence "The price of dingbats will be $5". I think the addition of the word "now" indicates not only that the change is happening now, but also that the new price is expected to persist. The sentence without "now" seems to refer to some instant in the future rather than an ongoing period.

An interesting question. I would say "now" focuses on the present time, but if a recent change is salient, it could be a conventional way to communicate a new state of affairs (that may last indefinitely).
Some examples that would likely be interpreted as "starting from now"—words in all-caps might be emphasized in speech:

(After putting on new eyeglasses:) Wow, I can SEE now!
Amazon is in the HEALTHCARE BUSINESS now. (They weren't before.)

But context may change the interpretation of whether the current state is likely to last long:

Amazon is in the healthcare business NOW, but new regulations could drive them out of the market.

"Right now" is a way to restrict to the immediate present time, without implying that something will last long-term (and perhaps implying that it won't).
